Locally Lipschitz function and continuity
In my book, when It comes to prove that the integral function Is continuos on an interval X, It shows that it's "locally Lipschitz" on X and, therefore, continuos.
At a First read, I didn't take much attention ( i knew a Lipschitz function Is also continuos so I thought It was obvious, as my book does) but then I realized It wasn't very obvious...
The definition of "locally Lipschitz" function I have is:
"A function f is locally lipschitz on X, if it Is Lipschitz on every compact set contained in X."
Now, it's obvious that every $x\in \mathbb{R} $ has a compact neighbourhood ( and so it is lipschitz on these and therefore continuos)
But what about our $X\subset \mathbb{R}$?
I thought something like this:
let's call
$$ inf(X)=a$$ $$ sup(X)=b $$
If $x=a$, then $[a,\beta] $ where $\beta \in X—\{a\}$, is a compact set contained in X and so that $x\in [a,\beta]$
Same thing in case $x=b$: $\alpha \in X—\{b\} $ and $[\alpha,x]$ Is a compact set contained in X and so that $x\in [\alpha,b]$
Finally, if $a<x<b$, then there exists $\delta>0$ so that $]x-\delta,x+\delta[\subset X$ (because X Is interval) and so, using $\delta^{'}< \delta$ (for example $\delta/2$) we have  $$[x-\delta^{'},x+\delta^{'}]\subset X $$
Once we know this:
Let $x\in X$, and let's consider a compact set contained in X that contain x (i proved that such a set exists). f is locally Lipschitz on this set, and so Is continuos on It, in particular It Is continuos in x, therefore It Is continuos on X.
I'd like to know if my proof Is correct, thank you!

Unless I'm overlooking something, I think you're making this WAY too complicated. Continuity is (or can be defined as) a pointwise condition. Pick $x \in \mathbb R.$ We show that $f$ is continuous at $x.$ We are essentially given that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in some closed interval containing $x,$ hence $f$ is continuous at all points in that interval, hence $f$ is continuous at $x$ (since $x$ belongs to that interval). If I'm overlooking something, maybe it's what you're using as the definition of "locally Lipschitz", in which case that definition should be included in your question.

Sorry, I see that you already have a definition of "locally Lipschitz" in your question. But I still don't understand what the issue is, in particular, why there might be a problem with the obvious argument I gave in my earlier comment.

well my function is defined on X so i can't pick x in all the real set (if the domain was R, as I said it's all obvious because I can always find a closed neighbourhood and so I can apply the property on that neighbourhood, obtaining that f is continuos at x, as you've done) The problem is that I'm working on X so the thing i was concerned about was "can I be sure I can find a compact set contained in X (so that I could apply the local lip. property) that contain x (so I could show the continuity at x) for all x in X?
